# Android Preference Screen to look like device admin

Tags: android, preference

i want to achieve the theme of the device admin in my preference screen, see image below to show what I mean.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZHnF.png

i have followed the example in sdk but ended up with something like this

http://i48.tinypic.com/b4xkl0.png

how can i achieve the first image?

**EDIT:** I found out it is actually a device default theme

Comment: If you can post your layout xmls it might be helpful. Looks like you are defining your own color themes (if you already extended  make sure to extent it by Theme.Holo. 
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo" /> (in styles.xml) and 
(In AndroidManifest.xml)
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"      android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

Comment: Hi Roller, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't notice it earlier, your are correct that I'm defining my own color themes in AndroidManifest.xml. After removing android:theme="@style/AppTheme" i was able to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to get the first view, you need to use MasterDetail View.
Left fragment is a List View (Categories) and the right view a Detailed view is again ListView with category detail items.

Check the MasterDetailView example at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html.

I am not sure the Preferences API supports this directly.

Comment: Thanks Roller for your comments, I was able to make the masterdetail style but my problem is I can't make it look like the one I needed, action bar, color, etc. (Note: have edited the image in the original post)

Comment: For ActionBar, the developer docs have the reference code: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html. The color you wanted is by the default Android Holo Theme you can set in the manifest XML. Refer: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html